# C# : Making generic type at runtime

Tags: c#, generics, reflection, system.reflection

I have an interface

```
public interface IBsonClassMap<T> 
    where T : class
{
    void Configure(BsonClassMap<T> map);
}
```

which serves as base for all mappings for mongo collections.

An implementation of it looks like this

```
public class StudentClassMap : IBsonClassMap<Student>
{
    void IBsonClassMap<Student>.Configure(BsonClassMap<Student> map)
    {
    }
}
```

I'm using an extension method to scan an assembly and invoke each mapping found.

This is it.

```
    public static void ApplyConfigurationFromAssemblies(this IServiceCollection services, params Assembly[] assemblies)
    {
        Type _unboundGeneric = typeof(IBsonClassMap<>);

        List<(Type Type, Type Handler, Type Argument)> types = new List<(Type, Type, Type)>();

        foreach (Assembly assembly in assemblies)
        {
            types.AddRange(assembly
                .GetExportedTypes()
                .Where(type =>
                {
                    bool implementsType = type.GetInterfaces().Any(@interface => @interface.IsGenericType && @interface.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == _unboundGeneric);

                    return !type.IsInterface && !type.IsAbstract && implementsType;
                })
                .Select(type =>
                {
                    Type @inteface = type.GetInterfaces().SingleOrDefault(type => type.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == _unboundGeneric);
                    Type argument = @inteface.GetGenericArguments()[0];

                    return (type, @inteface, argument);
                }));
        }

        types.ForEach(type =>
        {
            object classMapInstance = Activator.CreateInstance(type.Type);

            Type unboundGeneric = typeof(BsonClassMap<>);
            Type boundedGeneric = unboundGeneric.MakeGenericType(type.Argument);

            type.Handler.GetMethod("Configure").Invoke(classMapInstance, new object[] { boundedGeneric });
        });
    }
```

The issue is taht I'm getting

> Object of type 'System.RuntimeType' cannot be converted to type
> 'MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.BsonClassMap`1[Platform.Concepts.Mongo.Collections.Student]'.

Also, everything works as expected if I'm removing the argument in the Configure method of the IBsonClassMap, and addapt everhting accordingly. The method ends up getting invoked.

So instead of this

```
  type.Handler.GetMethod("Configure").Invoke(classMapInstance, new object[] { boundedGeneric });
```

I have this

```
   type.Handler.GetMethod("Configure").Invoke(classMapInstance, null);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are passing a `Type` into a method that expects a concrete class of `BsonClassMap<T>`

It seems you want

```
object classMapInstance = Activator.CreateInstance(type.Type);

Type unboundGeneric = typeof(BsonClassMap<>);
Type boundedGeneric = unboundGeneric.MakeGenericType(type.Argument);

// create the generic instance 
object o = Activator.CreateInstance(boundedGeneric);

type.Handler.GetMethod("Configure").Invoke(classMapInstance, new object[] { o });
```

<sub>***Note** : Completely untested, and based entirely on my spidey senses*</sub>